# Removing extra messages in completion minibuffer in emacs

Tags: emacs, completion, minibuffer

when I type in emacs shell and tab to complete, a completion minibuffer shows up and list the possible completions like this:

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    DEFAULTS_PATH
```

I was able to remove first two lines by setting `(setq completion-show-help nil)`. but is it possible to get rid of `possible completions are:`?  I just want a little bit of cleanness.

Comment: Took a look at the code: that's hardwired. Only way to get rid of it is to modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple hack around that message not being customizable is to just erase that line from the output buffer after `display-completion-list` runs (assuming you have already set `completion-show-help` to `nil`),

```
(define-advice display-completion-list (:after (&rest r) "remove-msg")
  (with-current-buffer standard-output
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (looking-at-p "Possible completions.*")
      (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (line-beginning-position 2)))))
```